# Zend navigation findActive returns null

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with Zend navigation and finding active element of menu.
I build an Zend 1.12 application with modules, and read the navigation from xml file.
I wrote a simple helper which store information about current page, and to find this page I use function:

```
protected function findDeepestActivePage()
{
    $naviHelper = $this->getView()->navigation();
    $renderInvisible = $naviHelper->getRenderInvisible();
    $result = $naviHelper->setRenderInvisible(true)->findActive($naviHelper->getContainer());
    $naviHelper->setRenderInvisible($renderInvisible);
    if (empty($result)) {
        return null;
    }

    return $result['page'];
}
```

But in few elements of menu that function can't find active element. Navigation part which is problematic(elements from menu users):

```
<admin route="admin.summary" id="admin" resource="admin.index.index" visible="1">
    <label>Panel Administracyjny</label>
    <pages>
        <main route="admin.summary" id="amain" resource="admin.index.index" visible="1">
            <pages>
                <summary route="admin.summary" resource="admin.index.index">
                    <label>Podsumowanie</label>
                    <module>admin</module>
                    <controller>index</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                </summary>
            </pages>
        </main>
        <users route="admin.users.list" resource="admin.user.index" id="users" visible="1">
            <label>Użytkownicy</label>
            <pages>
                <list route="admin.users.list" resource="admin.user.index" visible="0">
                    <label>Lista użytkowników</label>
                    <module>admin</module>
                    <controller>user</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                </list>
                <add route="admin.users.add" resource="admin.user.add" visible="0">
                    <label>Dodaj użytkownika</label>
                    <module>admin</module>
                    <controller>user</controller>
                    <action>add</action>
                </add>
                <details route="admin.users.details" resource="admin.user.details" visible="0">
                    <label>Szczególy użytkownia</label>
                    <module>admin</module>
                    <controller>user</controller>
                    <action>details</action>
                </details>
                <edit route="admin.users.edit" resource="admin.user.edit" visible="0">
                    <label>Edycja użytkownika</label>
                    <module>admin</module>
                    <controller>user</controller>
                    <action>edit</action>
                </edit>
            </pages>
        </users>
    </pages>
</admin>
```

I have other part of navigation with module panel and there is similar part in it and works fine. I try to solve the problem, but everything I found was not helpfull.